# How can I perform MySQL queries using the Laravel framework?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

So I recently looked into the Laravel framework as I've been wanting to do for several months and so far It looks great and has some really helpful stuff in it.

However I've been trying to actually use database queries so that I can make use of real data but when I've tried to I haven't had much success.

I've configured the `\config\database.php` MySQL section, then tried using `DB::` and all I got was an error:

> the DB class in controllers doesn't exist

I have been reading through all the documentation and found nothing

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class SongsController extends Controller {

        public function getSongs(){
        $songs = DB::table('songs')->get();

                return $songs;

        }      

}
```

View:

```
<?php  
        foreach ($songs as $song){
    var_dump($song->song);
        }
```

My mysql in \config\database.php:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'songs'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

Comment: Can we see a short piece of code that exhibits this problem? I imagine by seeing your code, a Laravel dev will be able to say what the issue is quickly.

Comment: And are you using .env file? ...if you got access denied for 'homestead'@'localhost' it have to be set somewhere

Comment: Nope not even sure what that is, I'm just trying to establish a connection between the running MySQL on my system and Laravel.

Comment: Look if you have an .env file on you root (not the .env.example, just.env).

Comment: Oh yeah I can see a .env file, why? Am I supposed to use that to configure my connection instead of the \config\database.php or what?

Comment: This file is used to set environement (local) variables, for example, config your local database so if you share your code or send it to production just not send this file (or git ignore) and database will be set on config file instead .env file. On "blank" Laravel installations this file doesn't exists.

Comment: So what should I do then since I'm never going to be sharing any of the code. This is a project purely for myself to both create and improve my Laravel knowledge on.

Comment: Then just delete the .env file

Comment: Now it just says Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mysql config:

```
'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'songs'),
```

It says: look if enviroment variable is set, if it exists in your .env file (in your root), use it, if not, use default "songs".

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: Ah, So If i set all of the config in .env to nothing like so, it will use what is set in the \config\database? 
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: It will use a empty database, user and password i think... like if you do $database = ""; Better if you delete the file if you don't need to use it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add use DB; in the top of your file. Remember Laravel5 uses namespaces.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
```

Comment: Already tried that there, I got an access denied state. SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I think you have missconfigured mysql (homestead is the default user/database in config file)